# Unauthenticated error after successful login with access token in Laravel Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel

I am encountering an issue with Laravel Sanctum. I am able to successfully login and receive an access token, but when I try to get user information after the login, I receive an "Unauthenticated" error. I have checked my code and made sure that the "auth:sanctum" middleware is applied in the constructor of the relevant controller. I am also using JWT as the driver for the "API" guard in the auth.php configuration file. I am not sure what could be causing this issue and would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve it.

auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'drivers' => [
    'jwt' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET'),
    ],
],
```

kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectForMultiLanguage::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\HideDebugbar::class,
            SetCurrentCurrency::class,
            SetLanguageForAdmin::class,
            RequireChangePassword::class
        ],
        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            RequireChangePassword::class
        ],
    ];
```

API route

```
/* Register - Login */
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api', 'prefix' => 'auth'], function ($router) {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login')->middleware(['throttle:login']);
    Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    Route::get('me', 'AuthController@me');
    Route::post('me', 'AuthController@updateUser');
    Route::post('change-password', 'AuthController@changePassword');

});

/* User */
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => ['api',],], function ($router) {
    Route::get('booking-history', 'UserController@getBookingHistory')->name("api.user.booking_history");
    Route::post('/wishlist','UserController@handleWishList')->name("api.user.wishList.handle");
    Route::get('/wishlist','UserController@indexWishlist')->name("api.user.wishList.index");
    Route::post('/permanently_delete','UserController@permanentlyDelete')->name("user.permanently.delete");

});
```

AuthController API

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:sanctum', ['except' => ['login','register']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'device_name' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->sendError('',['errors'=>$validator->errors()]);
        }

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        if (! $user || ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return $this->sendError(__("Password is not correct"),['code'=>'invalid_credentials']);
        }

        return [
            'access_token'=>$user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken,
            'user'=> new UserResource($user),
            'status'=>1
        ];
    }
```

UserController API

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }

    public function getBookingHistory(Request $request){
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $query = Booking::getBookingHistory($request->input('status'), $user_id);
        $rows = [];
        foreach ($query as $item){
            $service = $item->service;
            $serviceTranslation = $service->translate();
            $meta_tmp = $item->getAllMeta();
            $item = $item->toArray();
            $meta = [];
            if(!empty($meta_tmp)){
                foreach ( $meta_tmp as $val){
                    $meta[ $val->name ] = !empty($json = json_decode($val->val,true)) ? $json : $val->val  ;
                }
            }
            $item['commission_type'] = json_decode( $item['commission_type'] , true);
            $item['buyer_fees'] = json_decode( $item['buyer_fees'] , true);
            $item['booking_meta'] = $meta;
            $item['service_icon'] = $service->getServiceIconFeatured() ?? null;
            $item['service'] = ['title'=>$serviceTranslation->title];
            $rows[] = $item;
        }
        return $this->sendSuccess([
            'data'=> $rows,
            'total'=>$query->total(),
            'max_pages'=>$query->lastPage()
        ]);
    }
```

login respons API

```
access_token: "206|cVXaKEBbGVIw0aT8H6QFSmHEfC6DrsjbrdZ1byfe"
status: 1
```

login method endpoint

```
  login() {
    return this.http.post(this.api.base_url + 'auth/login', { email: this.email, password: this.password, device_name:this.email}).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.access_token) {
          const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${res.access_token}`,
          });
          this.http.get(this.api.base_url + 'user/booking-history',{headers:headers}).subscribe(user=>{
            console.log(user);
          })
        }
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

error:

```
message: "Unauthenticated."
require_login: 1
status: 0
```